# Why is my python module not found?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am learning python currently.

I am running pydev in eclipse.

Eclipse has the following folder in the PYTHONPATH:
/Users/peter/Documents/workspace/python

In that folder, there is a python package of: com.peter.minesweeper

in that folder i have 2 python modules: 
mineFileReader.py
minesweeper_practice.py

in the latter file i have the following code:

```
from com.peter.minesweeper import mineFileReader

reader = mineFileReader(pathToMinesFile = "minesweeper.mines.txt")
```

but i am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/peter/Documents/workspace/java/python/com/peter/minesweeper/minesweeper_practice.py", line 6, in <module>
    from com.peter.minesweeper import mineFileReader
ImportError: No module named minesweeper
```

This doesn't make sense because the 'python' folder is in the PYTHONPATH and the modules appear where they are declared. What am i missing here? thanks

Comment: That's a fairly suspicious package name (it implies java pretty heavily). How is it actually set up? To make that package, there should be three directories, each within the last, and each with an `__init__.py` file. I'm betting you're missing these "magic" files that mark a directory as a package.

Comment: that was totally it! all of the other packages had the __init__.py file, but that one folder did not. i must have added it as just a regular folder. never again!  submit that as an answer and i'll accept it. thanks.

Comment: One other thing, i come from a java-centric background, so BUSTED! i guess next i need to research how python packages are generally set up?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect<sup>*</sup> that you're missing the `__init__.py` files in one or more of your directories. This file is what lets Python know that a directory should be considered a package. So your directory structure should look like this:

```
python
  |-- com
      |-- __init__.py
      |-- peter
          |-- __init__.py
          |-- minesweeper
              |-- __init__.py
              |-- mineFileReader.py
              |-- minesweeper_practice.py
```

---

Also worth elaborating on my comment: needlessly long package names are generally avoided in Python. Probably you could put all this in one `minesweeper` package.

---

<sup>*Well, technically I *know*, since you told me so in the comments ;-)</sup>